# How to make Spring WebFlux FilePart runs asynchronously?

Tags: java, spring-webflux

I am doing file upload to S3 using Spring WebFlux, below is my code

**FileController.java**

```
public Mono<UploadResponse> upload(@RequestPart("file") Mono<FilePart> partMono) {
    return partMono
        .doOnNext(filePart -> log.info("Received File : " + filePart.filename()))
        .flatMap(filePart -> fileService.uploadFile(filePart));
  }
```

**FileService.java**

```
public Mono<UploadResponse> uploadFile(FilePart filePart) {
    try {
      log.info("Thread in ImageService: {}", Thread.currentThread().getName());e
      String fileName = filePart.filename();
      var fileUrl = fileRepository.getUrl(fileName);
      var targetFile = File.createTempFile(filePart.filename(), "");
      return filePart.transferTo(targetFile)
      .doOnSuccess(x -> {
        log.info("Thread in Mono: {}", Thread.currentThread().getName());
        fileRepository.uploadFile(targetFile, fileName);
        log.info("Delete file {}", targetFile.getAbsolutePath());
        targetFile.delete();
      })
      .thenReturn(UploadResponse.builder()
          .fileName(fileName)
          .url(fileUrl)
          .build());
    } catch (Exception e) {
      log.error(e.getMessage(), e);
      throw new FileUploadException("File upload fail. Reason: " + e.getMessage(), e);
    }
  }
```

**S3FileRepository.java**

```
public UploadResponse uploadFile(File file, String fileName) {
    log.info("Uploading {} to S3 bucket {}...", fileName, bucketName);
    try {
      var fileUrl = s3Client.getUrl(bucketName, fileName).toExternalForm();
      var request = new PutObjectRequest(bucketName, fileName, file);
      if(cannedAcl != null) {
        request.withCannedAcl(cannedAcl);
      }
      s3Client.putObject(new PutObjectRequest(bucketName, fileName, file));
      var response = UploadResponse.builder()
          .fileName(fileName)
          .url(fileUrl)
          .build();

      return response;
    } catch (AmazonServiceException e) {
      log.error("Upload of {}  to S3 bucket {} FAILED", fileName, bucketName);
      throw e;
    }
  }

  public String getUrl(String fileName) {
    return s3Client.getUrl("mybucket", fileName).toExternalForm();
  }
```

In the upload method of FileService I don't call any subscribe methods on FilePart but it still runs and calls the fileRepository method, why this works? And from the client side I have to wait a bit long to get result, how to make my upload async totally and return the result immediately?

Comment: where is the `fileRepository.getUrl` code? and also `File.createTempFile` is a `blocking` call. All file operations are blocking.

Comment: what should I do to avoid blocking code?

Comment: Google or read the reactor reference documentation.